# Save preset display configurations for quick-switch -- resolution, refresh rate, and display orientation. Is this possible?

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, display-settings, refresh-rate, orientation

I've used tools like Hotkey Resolution Changer but it only handle one monitor and not the display orientations. Is there anything that will remember all 3 attributes for quick-switching with hot keys?

I am on an Asus ProArt16_H7600HM running Windows 11 Pro. It has an NVIDIA RTX 3060. Currently I'm connecting two monitors using an HP G2 USB-C Dock. It has one HDMI and one DisplayPort so that's what I'm using. I'm happy to change to a different dock if needed.

Comment: Are you on Windows and which version? What is your computer model and its display adapter? Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1120749) your post to add the information.

Comment: I added the information! Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop configurations more fully saves [**DesktopOK**](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/DesktopOK/History) app.

Lots of useful settings.
Including Windows extended desktop - a mode that applies to multiple displays.